# Gradle Android repositories url issue

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependencies

I have a `library` module where I used a dependency which is based on a private maven repository, I can use this dependency in my `library` and everything works well.

The problem occurs when I try to use the `library` module inside my `application`, the build is failing, for some reason is looking to get this dependency from a different maven repository (in this case, my personal one, which is available only in my `app`)

I've switched from `implementation` to `api` and viceversa, just so check if this might solve the issue, but it is not.

If I add the maven repository url also in my `app`, everything works well, but I don't what that. Is this the expected behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, repositories declared in one subproject are not shared with other subprojects. Other than with Maven, repositories are also not taken from a dependency POM file or otherwise inherited from a dependency. On this topic, the Gradle docs [state the following](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#strict_limitation_to_declared_repositories):

> #### Strict limitation to declared repositories
>
> Maven POM metadata can reference additional repositories. These will be *ignored* by Gradle, which will only use the repositories declared in the build itself.

**However,** you can probably centralize the repository declaration in your top-level `settings.gradle(.kts)` file:

```groovy
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        // TODO Configure the shared repository here.
    }
}
```

You can find [more details on this centralization](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:centralized-repository-declaration) in the Gradle docs.